# How can I set the logger level with Quartz Scheduler and Cocoon?

Tags: quartz-scheduler, apache-cocoon

I have a project with an old version of Cocoon. There two cron jobs.

The project has the following log4j config:

```
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.conversionPattern=%d %-5p - %-26.26c{1} - %m\n

log4j.rootLogger=WARN,CONSOLE
```

In logs folder there exists file cron.log. But there are some `INFO` entries. How can I setup log level for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the following line to set the debug level of the `org.quartz` package.

```
log4j.logger.org.quartz=WARN,CONSOLE
```

BTW, you probably have something that configures this file appender (cron.log) because by default quartz (2.x) does not provides such configuration.

HIH